# Does Xpages support CSS

Tags: css, mobile-safari, xpages

I am trying to make some CSS for tables that will appear on an iPhone app. I want to, if possible, have a class style for a table that will always have two columns, and I want to set the column width and font and so on so I can just plunk down a table and give it the .PhoneTable class and it will always present the same way.

I constructed this CSS in Coda 2 for the Mac and tried it out and it worked.

When I added it it doesn't work. It appears that the iPhoneTable rules are getting displayed but none of the iPhoneTable td:nth-child(1) rules. When I preview it in a browser and look for at all of the CSS classes that are applied, those two are not there!

Why?

Is there a different way that I can easily apply one set of attributes to all the cells in the first column and another to the second?

```
.iPhoneTable {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Helvetic Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.iPhoneTable td:nth-child (1) {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: left;
    color: rgb(0, 122, 255) important !;
}

.iPhoneTable td:nth-child (2) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Here is the code that worked:

```
.iPhoneTable {
    width:100%;
    font-family:'Helvetic Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
.iPhoneTable td:nth-of-type(1){ 
width: 10%;
text-align:left;
}
.iPhoneTable td:nth-of-type(2){ 
text-align: right;  
}
.iPhoneTable td:nth-of-type(1){ 
color:rgb(0,125,255);   
}
```

Comment: just a guess but the space between the nth-child selector and the following ( looks strange to me... By the way: the important clause is wrong, should be
color:rgb(0, 122, 255)!important;

Comment: XPages outputs HTML and CSS - so yes, XPages supports CSS. Show us your code for creating your table - and your HTML output. Perhaps your table use other classes that override your .iPhoneTable CSS

Comment: OK I have a better idea of what is going on, but I really need some information. If I build a brand new clean XPage and just put the table in and the css, it works beautifully. The problem is when I start to build Xpages with the Single Application Mobile Control. As soon as I drop in a Application Page, all of the sudden Xpages includes customandroid.css and customiPhone.css and custommobile.css and so on.  This seems to be messing up my css. But I think I have to have it in there, as when I took of the _m prefix uses mobile, then the application didn't work.

Comment: Bryan, look at what classes your table use and then append/override the CSS properties for those classes with your changes

Comment: I have narrowed it down still further. When I run a small test XPage in the client all is well, but in a browser, the td:nth-child (1) is not applied. It is not crossed out or anything, it just isn't there. I checked to make sure my css was valid and it is valid CSS3 code, but not valid CSS2.1 code. My guess is that when Domino is deciding what to serve up it doesn't even use the CSS for nth-child. Maybe?

Comment: Show us your code. Domino does not decide to leave some CSS out. If the CSS file is sent to the browser, then all of it is sent. So something else is wrong.

Comment: OK Per, it was an error in my css. I didn't notice it in the editor. Once I fixed it, all worked well. I feel kind of stupid. I put the code that works in the original answer. Thanks once again.